# git rebase i vs git rebase --onto

Tags: git, git-rebase

I think I made a mistake. I wanted to delete some commit, so I used `git rebase -i` and deleted the last commit. But then it deleted all the changes I have made in my working directory and the stage ones. How can it be? I know I wouldn't have had this problem if I deleted some older commits. Is there a way to delete the last commit and keeping the changes in my working directory?

Btw, what is the difference between using `git rebase -i` and `git rebase --onto <branch name>~<first commit number to remove> <branch name>~<first commit to be kept> <branch name>`?

Comment: isn't "git reset --soft HEAD~1" what you need to revert the last commit, but keep its changed locally with the commit?

Answer (score 1):

`git rebase` won't launch at all if you've got uncommitted changes to known files. It'll fail with this error:

```
Cannot rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
```

Some variation of that error has been around since 2007. How did you launch `git rebase -i` at all?

That written, your question relates to `git rebase -i`'s defaults. Without any arguments, it'll default to the checked-out branch, and attempt to rebase it against the `<remote>/<branch>` configured to be 'upstream' of the branch you've checked out. You can check the branch's upstream repository and branch with:

```
git config branch.<branch_name>.remote
git config branch.<branch_name>.merge
```

Comment: so am I right if I say that deleting the last commit with `git rebase i` has the same effect than a `git reset --hard HEAD^` ?

Comment: Yes, they are functionally equivalent but only *in a clean repository.* `HEAD~1` might be more appropriate. If `HEAD` is a merge commit and you pass the `--preserve-merges` argument, I'm not sure how the `-i` output will handle the display of second parents. If your repository is dirty, and you've got unchecked-in work, `git reset --hard` will abandon those changes. `git rebase`, on the other hand, won't launch at all.